# New Relic for .Net?

Tags: asp.net, .net, profiler, newrelic

Is there anything like [New Relic](http://www.newrelic.com/) for .Net apps?

Comment: I could be wrong, but New Relic sounds like a profiler, which runs while the application is running for *real*, isn't that a bad idea ? 
be it for java or .net

Comment: Profiling is not inherently bad for performance. With the right tools it's fantastic and the only way to get real world insight into your app. New Relic profiles page render times and database times. It doesn't go deep into your app. The idea is to see which pages are taking the longest and then do deep profiling locally once you figure out where your site is spending most of it's time.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Sam, I'm happy to tell you that as of today, there is something that is very much like New Relic for .NET. It's New Relic for .NET. Same service, UI, pricing, etc. New agent that supports the .NET framework.  Try it out for free: https://newrelic.com/docs/dotnet/new-relic-for-net.

Answer (score 3):

dotTrace from jetbrains: http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/index.html

or

ants profiler: http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_performance_profiler/features.htm

I've used both and liked them both, not free though.

for insane profiling across processes and machines (in a SOA platform for instance) we have used dynaTrace http://www.dynatrace.com/en/  which is definately NOT free :)

Comment: Have you tried VSTS Test Edition at all?  I don't know much about it because we have VSTS Development Edition at work, but it seems to have some load testing capabilities.  I doubt that it's advanced as the specialized tools you've listed though.  Just curious..

Comment: we have used VSTS test edition for load testing, but I interpreted the question to be on profiling. VSTS works as a charm for load tests

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [Ruxit](http://www.ruxit.com), a new SaaS APM solution: http://blog.ruxit.com/net-monitoring-unlocked/ Its pretty cool!

Answer (score -1):

The IIS community has many tools for performance monitoring.

http://www.iis.net/downloads/Performance

Comment: Not one of those was even remotely close to New Relic. It's easy to look at perf counters but that's not very insightful as to WHERE the app is spending most of it's time.